# Hard coded to Dynamic values

Tags: php, mysql

I have been given a task to convert the hardcoded fields into dynamic fields.I have changed it partially to dynamic
Let me explain you the situation ,

We have a lot of databases and each database has a table by name Surveys

By using the DESCRIBE statement we will retrieve the fields in the Surveys table regardless of the database .

I need to know the way where we can loop again and again till all the fields in the survey table appears.

In the below code I have left the for loop blank .

Please let me know the changes that neeeds to be done to get this working

I would really appreciate any kind of help

```
function insertIntoUserUploadFileds() {

    $describe="DESCRIBE surveys";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `userUploadFields` (`fieldName`, `inUse`, `mandatory`, `type`, `mapTo`) VALUES";

    $inUse="0";
    $type="";

    //for(){
        if($field=='type'){
            $type="N";
        }elseif(($field=='fname') || ($field=='lname') || ($field=='phone')){
            $inUse="1";
            $type="T";
        }elseif($field=='email'){
            $inUse="1";
            $type="E";
        }

        //$sql .= "('".$field."', '".$inUse."', '0', '
        $result1 = mysql_query ($describe);
        $result = mysql_query ($sql);
    //}
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $result1 = mysql_query ('DESCRIBE surveys');

        //here is how you retieve all field and check
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

         $sql = "INSERT INTO `userUploadFields` (`fieldName`, `inUse`, `mandatory`, `type`, `mapTo`) VALUES";

           //here you can do if else to check the column name
           if($row['field']=='type')
            {
                $type="N";
            }
            else if(($row['field']=='fname') || ($row['field']=='lname') || ($row['type']=='phone'))
            {
                $inUse="1";
                $type="T";
             }

             else ($row['field']=='email')
            {
                 $inUse="1"
                 $type="E";
            }


           //build your query

           $sql .= "('".$field."', '".$inUse."', '0', '......)

           //execute your complete query
           $result = mysql_query ($sql);
        }//end of while
```

Comment: I am sorry if I have not explained it properly . I need to print the default values for all the fields that are printed from the surveys table

Comment: I really appreciate your patience . Thank you . Yes . By using the Describe statement we print all the fields . Along with he fields I also want to print the values .

Comment: Hey thank you very much . . I appreciate your help . Thanks once again

Comment: One last doubt . Will the $field still get the values in $sql statement ?

Comment: i think i understand what you want do , but which $field did you mean?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19615/discussion-between-jat-and-leon-yeo)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DESCRIBE`, if you are trying to retrieve the default `type` of a particular column you might look into this. It describes how to break down the information from a particular table. [Codex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-type.php)